# Recusively delete all files that do not contain a word in their title

Tags: linux, file, terminal

Hi I wanted to recursively delete all files in a directory with various folders that do not contain the word "weight" in their file name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type this command first:

```
find '/path/to/directory' -type f \! -iname '*weight*'
```

If you are OK with deleting all the files suggested by the command, then you can actually delete them with:

```
find '/path/to/directory' -type f \! -iname '*weight*' -delete
```

Comment: How would I do this is I wanted to exclude all files with either of two words in the title for example 'weight' and 'height' ? So one file might have 'weight' and another file might have 'height'.